# Jenkins CI/CD pipeline tools and stages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to understand the CI/CD pipeline. 
I know that there are different stages like getting the requirement (using JIRA), fetching the source code from SCM, building it (Maven, Ant, Gradle, NPM), Artifact archival (Nexus, JFrog, Artifactory), unit testing (JUnit), other testings and deployment.

I am missing some advanced steps like integrating tools like Code Quality check (SonarQube), Configuration Managment (Chef/Ansible), Deployment tools (Docker) and maybe more.

What would be a good example of a full Continuous Integration, Continuous Deployment and Continuous Delivery pipeline including the popular tools and plugins used with Jenkins for a Java, PHP, JavaScript or Node based project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in practice it all depends on your project, there is no silver bullet :)

Comment: Yes. It totally depends on the organization and the type of project you're working on. Here, I am just looking for an example for any type of organization and any type of project. Let's say a Java-based web application.